# JAXB unmarshalling error: Expected elements are <{ } Root>

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm reusing existing objects generated elsewhere to unmarshall XML data coming in as a String type.

The object:

```
/*  3:   */ import java.util.ArrayList;
/*  4:   */ import java.util.List;
/*  5:   */ import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
/*  6:   */ import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
/*  7:   */ import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
/*  8:   */ import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
/*  9:   */ import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
/* 10:   */ 
/* 11:   */ @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
/* 12:   */ @XmlType(name="", propOrder={"policy"})
/* 13:   */ @XmlRootElement(name="MyNodeResponse")
/* 14:   */ public class MyNodeResponse
/* 15:   */ {
/* 16:   */   @XmlElement(name="Policy")
/* 17:   */   protected List<Policy> policy;
/* 18:   */   
/* 19:   */   public List<Policy> getPolicy()
/* 20:   */   {
/* 21:65 */     if (this.policy == null) {
/* 22:66 */       this.policy = new ArrayList();
/* 23:   */     }
/* 24:68 */     return this.policy;
/* 25:   */   }
/* 26:   */ }
```

My unmarshalling code:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyNodeResponse.class); 
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
MyNodeResponse myNodeResponse = (MyNodeResponse)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlStringInput.getBytes("utf-8"))));
```

My input XML:

```
<ns2:MyNodeResponse 
         xmlns:ns2="mynamespace/2010/10">   
   <ns2:Policy>
   ....more data....
   <ns2:Policy/>
<ns2:MyNodeResponse />
```

I get the following error when unmarshalling:

```
unexpected element (uri:"mynamespace/2010/10", local:"MyNodeResponse"). Expected elements are <{}MyNodeResponse>
```

What exactly does the "{ }" refer to in the error, and how do I unmarshall in a way to match what is present in the input XML and how the object is expecting?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### What the Error Message is Saying

> What exactly does the "{ }" refer to in the error

In `{}MyNodeRespons` the `{}` portion refers to that qualified name not having the namespace URI portion set.

### How to Fix It

You need to map the namespace qualification using the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation:

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "mynamespace/2010/10",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: Thanks Blaise. Is the package level annotation the only way of mapping the namespace qualification in my case?

Comment: Nevermind that-I see the field/property level as well, though package level definitely seems better.

Answer (score 1):

there is `@XmlSchema` annotation that defines an attribute called `elementFormDefault`. In order to put the elements together with their namespaces, this atribute must be set to `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED`. This annotation should be defined in `package-info.java`